# list files from ssh server: unix

Tags: unix, ssh, eval, ls

I'm trying to list the files present on my remote server via ssh in my unix script & trying to store the output in a file.

Below is the snippet:

```
list_command="ssh -q $SSH_SERVER 'ls -l $PATH_ON_REMOTE_SERVER'"
list_value=`eval $list_command 1>file.txt`
```

Problem is that this snippet works in a fashion that it doesn't stores the value in '`list_value`' in '`ls -l`' format. Rather, it gives the output in one single line, space separated values.

If I execute just the eval statement without passing to a variable or file, the output is just perfect (in ls -l format)

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try redirecting the output directly to a file.
    ssh -q $SSH_SERVER 'ls -l $PATH_ON_REMOTE_SERVER' >>file.txt

Comment: redirecting the command didn't work. However, I redirected the eval output to a file & that worked. 

eval $list_command >> file.txt

Not sure if this file will be a regular file because I can't open this file in a while loop to read contents now.

while read line;
do
echo $line;
done <file.txt